# Using two templates with custom name in exams2pdf

Tags: r-exams

I am using `exams2pdf()` to generate two PDF files as:

```
exams2pdf(file = "ICvar.Rmd",
          name = "icvar",
          engine = "knitr",
          verbose = FALSE, 
          texdir = "tmptex",
          template = c("exam", "solution")
)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in base::file(out_tex[j], open = "w+", encoding = encoding) : invalid 'description' argument
```

Any ideas why?

Also, is it possible to use custom templates in `exams2nops()` like `template = c("exam", "solution")` to produce two PDF files, the first with the questions; the second with the solutions? I read the vignette but could not find any information and adding template to options in `exams2nops()` does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only provide a single `name = "icvar"` but actually need two distinct `name`s for `template = "exam"` and `template = "solution"`, respectively. Hence, lacking a second `name` lead to the somewhat cryptic error message. A simple solution is to provide a vector of two `name = c("icex", "icsol")`, say.

Additionally, I have just committed a fix to the development version on R-Forge that points this out more clearly in `?exams2pdf`, throws an intelligible warning, and provides a workaround. If you use your code above, `name` is changed to `name = c("icvar_exam", "icvar_solution")` automatically.

As for `exams2nops()`: Internally this essentially sets up a standardized `template` via `make_nops_template()` and then calls `exams2pdf()`. No additional templates can be provided. The reason for this is that all the convenient options in the NOPS template (e.g., adding an `intro`, selecting the `language`, switching to `twocolumn` layout, etc.) would only work for the NOPS template but not the other templates provided. Therefore, if you want to produce a solution sheet you have to use another call to `exams2pdf()` (or `exams2html()` or `exams2pandoc()`) after setting the same random seeds as for `exams2nops()`.

Comment: Thanks, once again, Achim. It did work for ```exams2pdf()```. As far as ```exams2nops()```, I guess you can make it work by using some ```options="solutions"``` and in that case the ```make_nos_template()```  would print the "X" inside the answer squares and print the solutions after the items... What would you say, maybe in a next release? (I do follow your suggestion and print exam2nops and exam2pdf using the same set seed number to get the same exercises and values, but the templates are quite different...)

Comment: Including the solution below the question is very easy, you can even do that on the fly: `exams2nops("deriv2", intro = "\\renewenvironment{solution}{\\textbf{Solution}\\newline}{}")`

Comment: Putting an "X" into the answer squares would require substantial rewrites of the NOPS template. It is not easy to combine the modularity of `\exinput{questionnaire}` with the precise layout for scanning. At least I haven't found an elegant solution for this, yet. Plus: Personally, I would be more interested in having the solution in HTML format rather than in PDF. The PDF is great for printing but for reporting the results I typically use the learning management system.